# Как сортировать по сумме двух колонок и взять по лимину?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-10

У меня есть такая таблица на `MySql`. Есть проблема по сротировке результатов по сумме двух колонок. Проблема в том что запрос нормально работает пока я не задаю лимит. Но когда в запросе есть и лимит. То оно берет просто по лимиту первые строки.

Кто может подсказать как с этим бороться  ?

Вот сома таблица.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это код на `Laravel`.

```
$this->model->whereHas('table1', function ($query) {
    return $query->select('*', DB::raw('A + B AS cnt'))->orderBy('cnt', 'DESC');
})->with(['table1'])->take($count)->get();
```

Comment: Код на Laravel делает совсем не то, что тебе надо. Он сперва сортирует. ВСЕ. А потом берёт это сортированное и лимитирует - но уже без сортировки. Та сортировка, что была внутри, снаружи немедленно херится. Так что либо добавь LIMIT во внутренний SELECT, либо добавь ORDER BY снаружи (и тогда убери внутри, за ненадобностью). Кстати, тебе отдельно поле cnt не нужно, сортируй сразу по raw выражению.

Comment: `Order` снаружи не работает по двум колонкам. А лимит внутри не работает.

Comment: @Akina А просто на `mysql` как можно это сделать?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY A + B DESC LIMIT 100;`

Comment: @Akina Нет там не одна таблица. если посмотреть на запрос.

Comment: А какая разница-то? на уровне SQL всё одно.

Comment: @Akina Я без `join` хотел как то на `laravel` сделать, с помощю `whereHas`. Ладно посмотрю этот способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спосибо большое пользователю `Akina` за хорошую мысль.

Вопрос решился так. С исползованием `laravel orderByRaw`.

Вот сам запрос.

```
    $this->model->orderByRaw('A + B DESC')
                ->with('user')
                ->get()->take($count);
```